# How to parse JSON string with array in php

Tags: php, json

I am sending a JSON string in php post request. JSON string look like this:

```
{"mobile":"0000000000","otp":"970996", "items":[{"pid":"12", "vid":"20"},{"pid":"13", "vid":"2"}]}
```

At server side i want to get mobile, otp and pid and vid for all items.

I am getting mobile number from this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
//print_r($data);
echo $data["mobile"];
```

But when i am trying to get pid and vid like this:

```
foreach($data["items"] as $mydata){

     echo $mydata->pid;
}
```

i am getting error: Trying to get property of non-object.

How to solve this?

Edit:

If there is any better way to parse JSON in php, please suggest that also.

Comment: try `echo $mydata["pid"];`

Comment: You've already used array syntax for `'mobile'`, why are you suddenly switching to use object syntax?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access `pid` with:

```
$mydata['pid']
```

You pass `true` as a second argument for [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

So you have to treat is as an array, not an object.